# vbscript, send file to PHP post

Tags: php, vbscript

I'm trying to send file using ADO. But it always gives the same error(800A0BBA).

```
Dim strURL, HTTP, dataFile, dataRequest, tmpDir 
Dim objStream
Set objShll = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
tmpDir = objShll.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%") & "\"

strURL = "https://www.example.org/accept.php"
Set HTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

objStream.Type = 1
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile tmpDir & "123123.file" '<<< The error points on this line.
set dataFile = objStream.Read
set dataRequest = "dataFile=" & dataFile

HTTP.open "POST", strURL, False
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(dataRequest)

HTTP.send dataRequest
```

I checked the file existence and permissions few times with different locations. Wrote the path different ways and still getting the error.

Comment: Print out `tmpDir & "123123.file"` and make sure it's the actual correct path to your file. Post it aswell.

Comment: It shows the correct path to the file.